# Puzzle with numbers in rings

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Find $x$ in the following shape. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The X is

> 3

That gives us the following equations:

> 9 = 4 + 3 + 2
>  16 = 7 + 3 + 6
>  36 = 2 * 3 * 6
>  84 = 4 * 3 * 7